# Addition of Double values does not output anything after decimal separator for round numbers (like 4 +4)

Tags: c#

I have declared two variables of type `double` in c# and using these for addition. But it is returning `int` in output. How could I return output as `double`. My expected Output is `8.0`.

```
double d = 4.0;
double d2;
d2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(d+d2));
```

**Output Window**

```
4.0
8
```

Program is giving output in double type if I pass any other value (i.e. 4.1) except 0 after decimal point (i.e. 4).

Comment: For a `double`, `8.0` and `8` are the same, if you want the number in a specific format you need to format it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's converting a `double` to a `string` using the most compact form possible.  Since the value does not have any fractional value it does not output the decimal digits.

> My expected Output is 8.0

Then specify that you want one digit after the decimal in the string output:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:N1}",Convert.ToDouble(d+d2));
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized my mistake.